# The call is ambiguous error for generics methods

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have struct like this:

```
public readonly struct SomeStruct<T1, T2>
{
   private readonly object _ref;

   public SomeStruct(T1 value)
   {
     _ref = value;
   }

   public SomeStruct(T2 value)
   {
     _ref = value;
   }

   public SomeStruct<U1, T2> Select<U1>(Func<T1, U1> mapLeft){ // logic... }

   public SomeStruct<T1, U2> Select<U2>(Func<T2, U2> mapRight) { // logic... }
}
```

And I try to use methods like this:

```
SomeStruct<int, string> someStruct = new SomeStruct<int, string>("test");

SomeStruct<bool, string> newStruct = someStruct.Select<bool>(x => true);
```

Or

```
SomeStruct<int, string> someStruct = new SomeStruct<int, string>(111);

SomeStruct<int, bool> newStruct = someStruct.Select<bool>(x => true);
```

But I'm getting error:
Error   The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'SomeStruct.Select(Func)' and 'SomeStruct.Select(Func)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the types explicitly because the compiler cannot infer the input types for your lambda expression.
For example,

```cs
SomeStruct<int, string> someStruct = new SomeStruct<int, string>(111);

SomeStruct<int, bool> newStruct = someStruct.Select<bool>((int x) => true);
```

---

**Why did this happen?**

You call `someStruct.Select<bool>(x => true)`. The type of someStruct is `SomeStruct<int, string>`. So in case of `Select<bool>` you have these methods for `someStruct`:

```cs
public SomeStruct<bool, string> Select<bool>(Func<int, bool> mapLeft) {}
public SomeStruct<int, bool> Select<bool>(Func<string, bool> mapRight) {}
```

Thus, your lambda expression `x => true` can be inferred to `Func<int, bool>` or `Func<string, bool>`. That's why you need to specify either `int` or `string` for the input parameter to avoid ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

I think the point is that both of these are valid:

```
var result1 = new SomeStruct<A, B>().Select<C>((A x) => new C());
var result2 = new SomeStruct<A, B>().Select<C>((B x) => new C());
```

... and therefore you **cannot** omit the type specifier for `x` like this:

```
var result2 = new SomeStruct<A, B>().Select<C>(x => new C()); // ERROR: CS0121
```

Also, the generics cannot be resolved based on the type of variable that the result gets assigned to.  Although adding the explicit type of the variable to which the result will be assigned **does** make it unambiguous which version will not be a syntax error **in this specific case**, C# does not make this inference and therefore doing this doesn't help:

```
SomeStruct<C, B> resultCB = new SomeStruct<A, B>().Select<C>(x => new C()); // ERROR: CS0121
SomeStruct<A, C> resultAC = new SomeStruct<A, B>().Select<C>(x => new C()); // ERROR: CS0121
```

I'm not sure *why* it doesn't make this inference, but it doesn't, so you'll have to explicitly provide the type of `x`.